# .Net Maui XAML Input field component

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I can't seem to find a simple text Input field to use in a .net maui xaml app. [Looking at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/) in the User interface/Controls/Views section there is a a number of components handling user interaction/input such as checkbox and slider and even a searchfield-component (Which to me should only be a specialized input field), but no text input.

How do I make a Input field using Xaml in .Net Maui?

(I did find [telerik](https://www.telerik.com/maui-ui), but I think it cost money and I was just looking for the "default" option)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

So now the Microsoft docs have been updated,

[Editor Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor)

[Entry Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry)

**OG ANSWER**:

From what I understand from the question you are either looking for an Editor or an Entry.

I am guessing the documentation is still incomplete or is incorrect

A basic implementation for it would look something like that:

Small textbox:

```
<Entry
  MaxLength="20"
  Style="{StaticResource CommonEntryStyle}"
  Text="This is the text." />
```

Multiline:

```
<Editor
  MaxLength="20"
  Style="{StaticResource CommonEditorStyle}"
  Text="This is the text." />
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that finds this like I did, the documentation is available now since June:

Single line [Entry component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry)

Multi-line [Editor component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor)